# Maximum possible rate of change of length-of-day?

Tags: celestial-mechanics

What is the maximum possible rate of change of length-of-day (in units of minutes per day), on Earth?  It is well known (and easy to observe) that it's larger near the equinoxes, and at higher latitudes, but how large can it be?

(Perhaps we can use [Seasonal changes in hours of daylight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827535/seasonal-changes-in-hours-of-daylight))

Comment: If by "day" you mean "sunrise to sunset", then the maximum change occurs at the poles.  Would "six months" or "a quarter of a million minutes" be an acceptable answer?

Comment: That's not really a change, though: the next day will be exactly as long.